# Angular 2 (rc5) router - sidebar navigation (child routing)

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm having problems figuring out how to properly do routes within routes. What I want to achieve:

```
App
  -Contacts (view)
  -News (view)
    SidebarNavigation (persistent throught news)
    -InfoOne (child-view of news)
    -InfoTwo (child-view of news)
```

news.component.html

```
<div class="sidebar-navigation>
  <a routerLink="/news/info-one" routerLinkActive="active">Info one</a>
  <a routerLink="/news/info-two" routerLinkActive="active">Info two</a>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now, the problem I encounter is whenever I click on `info-one`/`info-two` the sidebar navigation disappears. How do I tell angular to display child-views within the child `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and not in the main `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

I have create a fork [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g40akEtDO2qdvPeLuqsN?p=preview) out of the official tutorial.
Take a look at: `app/news.component.ts` and `app/app.routing.ts`

---

Some more code:
`app.routing.ts`:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ContactComponent }  from './contact.component';
import { NewsComponent, InfoOneComponent, InfoTwoComponent }  from './news.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/news',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'news',
    component: NewsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'news/info-one',
    component: InfoOneComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'news/info-two',
    component: InfoTwoComponent
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is with the `Routes`, update it as below,

You have defined child routes and it needs to go inside children array. when you don't add in children it is loading in the main `router-outlet` rather than the one which you have added inside the news component.

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/news/info-one',
  pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 {
  path: 'contact',
  component: ContactComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'news',
  component: NewsComponent,
  children : [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/news/info-one',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'info-one',
   component: InfoOneComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'info-two',
    component: InfoTwoComponent
  }
]
}];
```

Updated the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/g4UTf82IBtZh6DmVoYLf?p=preview)

Comment: `children` was what I was looking for :) Thanks a lot, though it seems you've messed up the plunker a bit, it only shows info-one. I've corrected it, if you can, please update it in your post for future reference. [updated-plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g4UTf82IBtZh6DmVoYLf?p=preview) Also, you don't need all that extra :id stuff.

Comment: thanks for the updated plunker added in the answer, I was actually trying some stuff didn't realize that am updating the plunker added in answer.